# Adding a symbol after each element in CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, border, navbar

I need to make a navigation bar, with symbol " | " between each link. I tried using

`.navbar li::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:" | ";
}`

But I always end up getting the first symbol under the link, I dont know why.

http://prntscr.com/c34zrf

I also tried using border-right and border-left, but that looks very ugly and gives me 2 lines for every element.

http://prntscr.com/c350gw

Comment: It looks fine on my comp. I would disable position absolute. Can you provide link where we can help you troubleshoot your issue?

Comment: Not really, it might look fine on your PC cause i have logo on the left side of the navbar, I dont know if that matters though

Comment: I assume you get 2 lines because you use border-right AND border-left? Maybe just use one of both?

Comment: Yes, but then it's gonna look ugly and im gonna end up with having only "left or right" on the last one.

Comment: Well, change the rule for the last element only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's how I usually do this building on your border-right solution: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3wwn2vo/)

**HTML:**

I include a span to apply the border to as it means the border will keep the height of the text. If you want to add padding to the list, apply horizontal padding to the li and vertical padding to the span.

```
<ul>
  <li><span>Link 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Link 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Link 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

you can use :first-child to remove the border which should work all the way back to [IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-child)

**CSS:**

```
ul{

  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;

}

li {

  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 0px;

}

span {

  padding:0px 10px;
  border-left:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;

}

li:first-child span {

  border-left:none;  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wholeheartedly agree with Christopher Thomas' method, it's actually quite clever.
I thought of another potential way you could do it.

Put the links in three separate paragraphs and make two divs, which will be the lines.
Then you can still format them separately to look like lines.

The lines are not perfectly centered vertically but it's the best I can do in five minutes.

```css
div {
    background: #fe89d7;
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
        <body>
            <p>Link 1</p>
            <div></div>
            <p>Link 2</p>
            <div></div>
            <p>Link 3</p>
        </body>
```